# Refactoring a function with different signature

Tags: java

I call several WebServices which return each a different exception type:

```
try {
   //calling first WS1 here
} catch (my.package1.FaultWS_Exception e) {
        StringBuilder sb = getMessageFromException(e);
        log(sb);
}

try {
   //calling first WS2 here
} catch (my.package2.FaultWS_Exception e) {
        StringBuilder sb = getMessageFromException(e);
        log(sb);
}
```

my `getMessageFromException` simply returns a pretty printed message from the exception.

But as my exceptions are in different packages (each method is in a different WS), I had to create different `getMessageFromException()` functions for each exception:

```
private StringBuilder getMessageFromException(my.package1.FaultWS_Exception e) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    if (e.getFaultInfo() != null) { //returns my.package1.FaultWS
        sb.append(e.getFaultInfo().getDescfault());
        sb.append("\n");
        sb.append(e.getFaultInfo().getCodefault());
        sb.append("\n");
    } else if (e.getMessage() != null) {
        sb.append(e.getMessage());
        sb.append("\n");
    }
    return sb;
}

private StringBuilder getMessageFromException(my.package2.FaultWS_Exception e) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    if (e.getFaultInfo() != null) { //returns my.package2.FaultWS
        sb.append(e.getFaultInfo().getDescfault());
        sb.append("\n");
        sb.append(e.getFaultInfo().getCodefault());
        sb.append("\n");
    } else if (e.getMessage() != null) { 
        sb.append(e.getMessage());
        sb.append("\n");
    }
    return sb;
}
```

This code looks very ugly and a bit repetitive (I have 4 different signatures so far), is there a way to refactor it ? knowing that the Exceptions are defined the same, except from the package name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the faultInfo properties are identical for every case, you could use reflection:

```
try {
   //calling first WS1 here
} catch (my.package1.FaultWS_Exception e) {
        StringBuilder sb = getMessageFromException(e, e.getFault());
        log(sb);
}

try {
   //calling first WS2 here
} catch (my.package2.FaultWS_Exception e) {
        StringBuilder sb = getMessageFromException(e, e.getFault());
        log(sb);
}
```

...

```
private StringBuilder getMessageFromException( Exception e, Object faultInfo )
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    if ( faultInfo != null )
    {
        FaultInfo genericFault = asGenericFault(faultInfo);
        sb.append( genericFault .getDescfault() );
        sb.append( "\n" );
        sb.append( genericFault .getCodefault() );
        sb.append( "\n" );
    }
    else if ( e.getMessage() != null )
    {
        sb.append( e.getMessage() );
        sb.append( "\n" );
    }
    return sb;
}

private FaultInfo asGenericFault( Object fault )
{
    try
    {   
        Class<? extends Object> faultType = fault.getClass();
        String descfault = (String) faultType.getMethod( "getDescfault").invoke( fault );
        String codefault = (String) faultType.getMethod( "getCodefault").invoke( fault );

        return new FaultInfo(descfault, codefault);
    }
    catch ( Exception e )
    {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException( "expected a type with public getDescfault() and getCodefault() methods but got: " + fault, e );
    }
}
```

FaultInfo would be a simple Java Bean with the 2 properties you need.

Answer (score 3):

Simply use one method for all type of Exceptions.

Make it `public static` and move into a utility class.

```
public static StringBuilder getMessageFromException(Exception e){...}
```

Why do you need overloaded methods for different type of Exceptions?

User defined Exceptions are also subtype of Exception itself.

---

--EDIT--

create an interface for all your custom exceptions having  `getFaultInfo()` method.

```
interface MyFaultWS {} // marker interface
class FaultWS implements MyFaultWS {} // do it for both the packages

interface FaultInfoException {FaultWS getFaultInfo();}

// do it for both the packages
class FaultWS_Exception extends Exception implements FaultInfoException {

    @Override
    public FaultWS getFaultInfo() {
        return ...; // return your package specific exception
    }
}
```

Finally use

```
public static StringBuilder getMessageFromException(FaultInfoException e){...}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I wouldn't be able to call `e.getFaultInfo()` as it doesn't exist in `Exception`. And also `Exception` is not really a tag relevant to this question :)

Comment: Have a look at my updated post.

Comment: Finally you can do one thing **extract the part that is common** in all the methods and put in a separate method to reduce the redundant code.

Comment: what's the part that is common in that particular case?

Comment: I think only else part is common.

Comment: use `System.lineSeparator()` instead of `\n` for line separator.